# merge origin/master not behaving as expected

Tags: git

My understanding of using `origin` as part of a path in git is that you are dealing with the server version of the code; as a result (conflicts, etc aside), I would expect the following two sets of commands to behave in the same manner (assume my branch in mytestbranch, and starting with that branch checked out):

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout mytestbranch
git merge master
```

And the more terse:

```
git merge origin/master
```

However, it would appear that origin/master doesn't always get the latest version from the server.  Am I misunderstanding what this is intended to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`origin/<branch>` merely contains the remote content since *the last time you've `fetch`ed from it*.

`git pull` is the same as a `git fetch` + `git merge origin/<branch>` (technically, `git merge FETCH_HEAD`, [see here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)):
`git fetch` will bring your remote branches up to date and `git merge origin/master` will merge the changes just fetched to your local branch (I assume here that' you have remote tracking branches set up).

The key here is that only when you do a `git fetch` or `git push` (or `git pull`, as just explained), your repository will connect to a remote. All other operations are performed *locally*.

Another small difference between your two examples is that `git merge origin/master` on some branch different than master will merge in the latest fetched changes of remote master to that branch, but it won't update your *local* master (you can only update a local branch when it's currently checked out).

By the way, a nice website to learn about remotes and remote branches "graphically" is https://learngitbranching.js.org/?NODEMO. The official [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) contains a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`origin/master` is a *remote-tracking* branch.

Its job is to track the state of the remote branch, **even offline**. Which means that each time you want to sync between the real remote branch and the image you use to represent it (the remote-tracking branch in question, `origin/master`), you have to explicitly do it with

```
git fetch
```

Then, git will send a request to your remote for an updated version of all branches (if any are updated or new). (check [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))